# How do I change the code highlighting color to a more readable color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

[image]

Specifically... How do I change this code highlighting background color in VS 2013/2015 when inside an Array.ForEach / List.ForEach code block?

It appears I have good color EXCEPT when I am inside a ForEach code block.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Color

There you can edit the color.

Greatings.

Comment: Specifically, which one controls the high-light color within the 'ForEach' block?

Comment: User Types (Enums), try edditing this one.

Comment: None of the 'User Types' have that whitish background color... so it's not those :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Color -> **Active Statement**

Thanks to @bugs2919 for pointing the right direction!